# Cast extension media customization

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

**Context**

Looking at the guidelines for a web app, I see that we need to choose between using the cast extension to show information about the content being casted on the receiver or to implement the persistant controls.

[image]

**Problem**

It's pretty difficult to understand how to do implement it. And it's not only about showing a title and an image, it's also about the pause/sound/config button in the extension.

Do we need to send additional media info with the metadata, like chrome.cast.media.MetadataType or chrome.cast.media.MovieMediaMetadata?

Answer (score 0):

On the sender side, Cast extension will take care of showing play/pause/volume button, which acts as a media control, when a cast session is live.

On the receiver side developers can customize and are encouraged to show meta data about the media being cast e.g. title, subtitle, thumb image, etc.  They should not interfere with the main media content. Additional media info with metadata need to be set/sent by developers from sender side.  See this example CastMedia for sample code.

https://github.com/googlecast/CastMedia-chrome

Comment: Yes, we're doing that but even within your code examples, it doesn't work; we don't see any data on the cast extension and neither the play/pause/volume buttons :/

Comment: If you desire to add media custom control inside the Cast extension pop-up, that's not possible.  Currently the Cast extenson UX includes Play/Pause/Volume, Stop, and meta data receiver app name and device name, and it will be improved over time but developers have no way to hook into it and customize.

Comment: Is there any explicit configuration or something we need to send with the media to show the controls in the extension?

Comment: Nothing necessary from apps.  It's all done by Cast extension.

Comment: Cool. We've just found that is working perfectly with the new beta extension (14.402.0.3)
Thanks!